# ¿Cómo crear variables con nombres de números consecutivos en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, variables, input

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Quiero declarar variables en JavaScript que al final del nombre tienen un número consecutivo, como: general0, general1, general2, etc. Esta parte la solvente con

```js
window['general' + i]
```

Puesto que lo estoy haciendo en un bucle for. El problema viene en el valor que quiero asignarle a las variables, que es el texto de un input. Ahora mismo, he declarado las variables, una por una de la siguiente manera:

```js
general0 = document.rellenar.general0.value
general1 = document.rellenar.general1.value
general2 = document.rellenar.general2.value
general3 = document.rellenar.general3.value
general4 = document.rellenar.general4.value
```

Donde "rellenar" es el archivo .js donde toma el valor del input text con id = "general0..1..2" Pero son más de 60 variable y por eso quiero hacerlo en un for. Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```js
 var idGeneral = new Array();
    idGeneral.push("general0", "general1", "general2", "general3", "general4", "general5", "general6", "general7", "general8", "general9", "general10", "general11", "general12", "general13", "general14");

    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        window['general' + i] = document.rellenar.idGeneral[i].value;
    }
```

Lo que arroja un error al intentar colocar los elementos del array. Asumo que es porque son tipo string pero no se de qué otra forma colocarlo.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas crear variables ni arreglos para acceder a cada elemento y su respectivo valor, basta con que todos los *input* tengan el mismo nombre, con corchetes para que sean manejados como un arreglo cuando los proceses en el servidor.

Con [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) puedes obtenerlos todos y acceder por índice, como si se tratara de un arreglo.

```js
let inputGeneral = document.querySelectorAll('[name="general[]"]');

// Acceder a cada elemento por su índice
console.log(inputGeneral[0].value);
console.log(inputGeneral[5].value);
console.log(inputGeneral[10].value);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="general[]" value="General 0"><br>
<input type="text" name="general[]" value="General 1"><br>
<input type="text" name="general[]" value="General 2"><br>
<input type="text" name="general[]" value="General 3"><br>
<input type="text" name="general[]" value="General 4"><br>
<input type="text" name="general[]" value="General 5"><br>
<input type="text" name="general[]" value="General 6"><br>
<input type="text" name="general[]" value="General 7"><br>
<input type="text" name="general[]" value="General 8"><br>
<input type="text" name="general[]" value="General 9"><br>
<input type="text" name="general[]" value="General 10"><br>
```

Si no pueden compartir el nombre, entonces les asignas una clase:

```
<input type="text" class="general" name="cualquier_nombre" value="General 1">
```

Y en Javascript solo cambias el selector para obtener por clase:

```
let inputGeneral = document.querySelectorAll('.general');
```

Comment: funcionó tu propuesta. Había conseguido hacer algo rudimentario pero funcional, que fue ingresar el valor del input text con Jquery. Ahora mismo lo cambio por tu respuesta. Agradecido.